# Symbolism of Occam's death in Straight Man?

Tags: symbolism, richard-russo, straight-man

In Richard Russo's novel *Straight Man*, the protagonist Hank claims to be a philosophical disciple of William of Occam, and applies Occam's razor to his approach to deduction many times.  As I recall, the use of Occam's razor was the only way in which Hank considered himself a disciple of this William, which is also Hank's given name.

He names his dog Occam, which escapes from his house near the climax of the book, and is hit by a car and killed by one of his colleagues, Finny.  This provides some natural narrative symmetry by leading to a scene at the end where he buries his dog with his estranged dying father looking on, complementing a scene from the beginning where his father buries a dog with him as a child looking on.  One could also read into Occam's death some symbolism regarding the distance Hank puts between himself and others in his relationships.  Putting those points aside:

> Is there any significance that a character named "Occam", rather than just Hank's dog, dies at the end?  For instance, is there any evidence that Hank no longer so strongly subscribes to Occam's razor?